# Xamarin : Convert image to Pdf format in Xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin, uwp

I am getting error width cannot be null , when passing image to inputstream.As i didn't find any alterante method . Basically i want to convert image to Pdf format in Xamarin.forms which supports UWP platform . 
I am using xfinium pdf library for this.

---

```
public void ConvertJpegToPdf()
            {
                try
                {

                    PdfFixedDocument document = new PdfFixedDocument();
                    Xfinium.Pdf.PdfPage page = document.Pages.Add();
                    page.Width = 800;
                    page.Height = 600;

                    var imageStream = GetStream();
                    PdfJpegImage jpeg = new PdfJpegImage(imageStream);//<-Error

                    PdfStandardFont helvetica = new PdfStandardFont(PdfStandardFontFace.Helvetica, 24);

                    PdfBrush brush = new PdfBrush(PdfRgbColor.Red);

                    page.Graphics.DrawImage(jpeg, 0, 0, page.Width, page.Height);
                    Stream pdfStream = null;
                    document.Save(pdfStream);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }

           }


    protected Stream GetStream()
            {
                byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("http://david.qservicesit.com/images/3.jpg");
                MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
                return stream;
            }
```

> Please suggest some alternate to do this

Answer (score 0):

> `byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("http://david.qservicesit.com/images/3.jpg");`

You could not get image stream in this way. The method you have used can only get the `Bytes` of string. For your scenario, you could use [http](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http/) client to acquire image stream. Please refer to the following code:

```
public async Task<Stream> GetStream()
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    HttpResponseMessage res = await client.GetAsync(new Uri("http://david.qservicesit.com/images/3.jpg"));
    Stream stream = await res.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
    return stream;
}


public async Task ConvertJpegToPdf()
{
    try
    {
        PdfFixedDocument document = new PdfFixedDocument();
        Xfinium.Pdf.PdfPage page = document.Pages.Add();
        page.Width = 800;
        page.Height = 600;

        var imageStream = await GetStream();
        PdfJpegImage jpeg = new PdfJpegImage(imageStream);
        PdfStandardFont helvetica = new PdfStandardFont(PdfStandardFontFace.Helvetica, 24);
        PdfBrush brush = new PdfBrush(PdfRgbColor.Red);

        page.Graphics.DrawImage(jpeg, 0, 0, page.Width, page.Height);
        Stream pdfStream = new MemoryStream();
        document.Save(pdfStream);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }

}
```